Sum values of data.table column 2 by all rows greater than x in column 1
I have a data.table with many rows and columns. The first column is an "index" and the other columns contain values generated by some upstream code. Like this:
       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
1:     1    15    14
2:     2     9     9
3:     3    12    11
4:     4     1    19
5:     5    11    13

I would like to group on Column "A" and (independently) sum values in "B" and "C" for all rows where "A" is greater than or equal to the group value. So, for row one, the value in Column B should be the sum of all values in Column B. For row two, the value in Column B should be the sum of all values in Column B, except for the value in row one, and so on...
So the result would look like this:
       A     B     C
   <int> <int> <int>
1:     1    48    66
2:     2    33    52
3:     3    24    43
4:     4    12    32
5:     5    11    13

Here is the example data.table:
dt <- structure(
  list(
    A = 1:5,
    B = c(15L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 11L),
    C = c(14L, 9L, 11L, 19L, 13L)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
)

I'm close with this attempt but I can't figure out how to apply it to many columns:
dt[, .(B = sum(dt$B[.I:nrow(dt)]), C = sum(dt$C[.I:nrow(dt)])), by = .(A)]


try this: dt[,lapply(.SD,function(x)rev(cumsum(rev(x)))),,.SDcols = 2:3]

dt[,lapply(.SD, \(x)x + sum(x) - cumsum(x)),,.SDcols = 2:3]

dt[,lapply(.SD,\(x)sum(x) - cumsum(c(0, x[-.N]))),,.SDcols = 2:3]
